# angularjs load indicator doesn't clear when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using the following code, my loading indicator appears to work. However, the loading indicator does not disappear if someone reloads a page in the browser. This does not happen on the index or root. Using `console.log()` I can see that 'loading-complete' has been broadcasted, but the directive does not get updated. Any ideas?

I'm using the following code in my angularjs config:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $rootScope) {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('loading-started');
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        'response': function(response) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('loading-complete');
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Coupled with the following directive:

```
.directive("loadingIndicator", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        template: "<div>Loading...</div>",
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on("loading-started", function(e) {
                element.css({"display" : "block"});
            });

            scope.$on("loading-complete", function(e) {
                element.css({"display" : "none"});
            });
        }
    };
})
```

And lastly, the HTML:

```
<div class="loading" loading-indicator></div>
```

Comment: Instead of making the directive show/hide the loading indicator based on an event, why don't you tie it to some state variable (that can be saved in $rootScope)?

Comment: I forgot to mention that what could be happening is that when the loading-indicator is first drawn on the page, it may not catch the loading-complete event, which is why I suggested to tie it a state

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example using a state variable?

Answer (score 0):

When the Http request fails, the interceptor's response function will not be called. Try adding 'responseError' handler as well, that also broadcasts the event.

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading-complete');
    if (canRecover(rejection)) {
      return responseOrNewPromise
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried variations, including both responseError and requestError functions but I omitted them from the above since the problem persists with or without them.

Comment: Is the css class "loading" is set to "display:none" by default?

Comment: It is not. I would accept this as an answer if I could. Having said that, I suppose I have the opposite issue now. If I do a reload of the page, the loading indicator is never displayed. In both cases, subsequent clicking around the interface results in the loading indicator working properly. It just appears that the broadcast is not being acted upon… too early, perhaps? Nonetheless, having the CSS default set is better than not.

Comment: Glad I could help,a bit :-)